# Parse cloud signup, login using JS promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'd like to create a parse.com cloud function that will either login or signup a user depending on if the credentials are recognized.  I think I'm getting tripped up on promises, particularly on parameters to the then and error functions.

This function works:

```
function signUp(params) {
  var password = "my app supplies the password";
  var user = new Parse.User();

  user.set("username", params['email']);    // in my app, email==username
  user.set("password", password);
  user.set("email", params['email']);

  return user.signUp(null);
}
```

Calling it like this produces a good signUp result:

```
app.post('/reg', function(req, res) {
  signUp(req.body).then(function(user) {
    res.render('myView', { username: Parse.User.current().get('username') });
  }, function(user, error){
    res.render('myView', { username: 'error' });
  });
});
```

Similarly, this one works called in exactly the same way:

```
function logIn(params) {
  var username =  params['email'];
  var password = "my app supplies the password";
  return Parse.User.logIn(username, password);
}
```

Here's the problem, why doesn't this one work?  called in the same way...

```
function logInOrSignUp(params) {
  logIn(params).then(function(user) {
    return user;
    // or should this be return Parse.Promise.as(user); ?
    // this is where I've become confused.
  }, function(user, error) {
    // login failed, let's take that to mean the user is new
    // issue: are these the right params for the error function?
    // the parse docs seem to indicate that login error block takes two params
    // issue: signUp(params) can return a promise, does this
    // return that promise from the function?
    return signUp(params);
  });
}
```

When I post to this with either an existing email address (username) or a novel one, I get "Server Error" back.  (As an aside, I find myself clueless about how to debug. My dev loop is research-guess-code-deploy-inscrutableError-repeat...).

Comment: the F12 button is your friend in most browsers for debugging. You could try your two methods and see the difference in the headers that are being sent to the service. As F12 differs largely depending on browsers (awesome in chrome, slow and difficult to use in IE) and/or other clients may be involved, I prefer Fiddler to get the whole picture in the same app when debugging service calls.

Comment: You return a promise in the onRejected handler, so [according to the spec](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#point-59), the promise returned by `then` should take on that promise's state. Now you need to do something with the promise returned by `then`. Add an onFulfilled and onRejected handler (another chained `then` call) and do something with the value/reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution turns out to be simple.  That `then()` method in my `logInOrSignUp()` function returns a promise, but my code fails to return it.

```
function logInOrSignUp(params) {
  return logIn(params).then(function(user) {
    return user;
  }, function(user, error) {
    return signUp(params);
  });
}
```

The return statements in the callback parameters are a little distracting.  They run when the promise is fulfilled and start the next promise, but the function still needs to return what it 's caller's expect.

[I think Burt Bacharach said it best...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promises,_Promises_%28musical%29)